# Laravel - Delete local file after served to client

Tags: php, download, laravel-5.1, response

I am using the following to serve a PDF file to a user return

```
response()->download($filename);
```

Once the file has been served for download, there is no need to keep it on the server and I would like to remove it so they don't clog the server storage. What is the best way to remove the file after it has been downloaded? I was going to use terminable middleware to handle it. Is that the best way to do it with Laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to post this here in case anyone else has this question...

It is possible to flash the file name to the session and then use terminable middleware to fetch the session variable and unlink the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a queue and have a delete job run to remove the file at a certain interval after the file download.

Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues) is a pretty neat one.

Comment: was trying to avoid crons or queues for this purpose. I posted an answer of my own that I found.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make Event/Listener system, so that code would remain clean.

**1.step**

```
EventServiceProvider.php
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\FileHaveDownloadedEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\FileHaveDownloadedListener',
    ],
];
```

**2.step** `php artisan event:generate`

in your model

write like so

```
  Event::fire(new FileHaveDownloadedEvent(['filename' => $filename]));
```

// Listener

```
public function handle(FileHaveDownloadedEvent $event)
{
    unlink('/directory/where/file/located/'.$event->filename);
}
```

As well you could make queues :)

Good luck!